# Safari redirection adding comma causing 404

Tags: nginx, safari, cloudflare

I have a website running in Nginx and Cloudflare. It has several url checks and redirection. For example, when use hits `example.com`, they will be redirected to `example.com/en/`, these are done in nginx. In Chrome and Firefox they all work fine, but in Safari, when I hit example.com, it becomes:

`http://example.com/en/,%20http://example.com/en/`

This is causing 404. Any suggestions?.

Answer (score 0):

This definitely wouldn't be coming from CloudFlare's side unless you've manually created a PageRule to redirect content on your site. If you haven't manually created a PageRule at CloudFlare though you can rule out that as the location/cause of the issue.

If you have created a PageRule at CloudFlare to redirect content I'd suggest opening a support ticket directly with CloudFlare so our support team can review your specific account settings.

p.s. I work at CloudFlare.